# Embed PDF in webpage using Dot Net Nuke Wizard

Tags: html, dotnetnuke

I am attempting to embed a PDF file within my webpage. I am updating the webpage through Dot Net Nuke.

**My Problem:** I am adding the below HTML in Dot Net Nuke's page edit wizard. When I click save after adding the new HTML, and go to visit the webpage I updated the HTML(for the iframe) is not there? Does Dot Net Nuke not allow embedded PDF's or something?

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://mypdf.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is sooo much easier if Dot Net Nuke would let me write the .aspx files myself. **Do you know how I can embed a PDF using Dot Net Nukes wizard?**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to include an iFrame within the DotNetNuke HTML module.
But if that is causing trouble - then edit the 'settings 'for that specific HTML module that you have added to the page.

Add your code into the 'footer' section in that modules settings. That will put your code directly on the page and will not be tampered with by the HTML editor.

Answer (score 0):

The default HTML editor configuration is designed to strip stuff like IFrames from your content.

If you are logged in as  host user you can go to "Host" -> "Html Editor Configuration Manager" and disable the options that strip this content.